# Nested replace for update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have package with cursor and I want to replace some characters on a column? The select works but I need to update, thank you.
Here is my code :

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR get_data
    IS
        SELECT e.column1,
               e.column2,
               d.column3,
               d.column4
          FROM table1 e, table2 d
         WHERE e.column1 = d.column3;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN get_data
    LOOP
        UPDATE table1
           SET column1 = REPLACE (REPLACE (column1, 'OPRS', 'V'), 'ABV', 'T')
         WHERE column1 = i.column1
           AND column1 LIKE '2027044%';

        UPDATE table2
           SET column3 = REPLACE (REPLACE (column3, 'OPRS', 'V'), 'ABV', 'T');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The error is:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB_KSS_ONLINE.NETOPERIDX) violated ORA-06512: at line 10
00001. 00000 - "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause: An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action: Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Comment: Please do not edit answers into your question. Also, please update your question with an [MCVE] including some example data that demonstrates your problem and the expected output for that data and what the problem is with your attempt (i.e. what about the "update" statement does not work).

Comment: @Spec . . . What does "not work" mean?

Comment: @Spec That error is self explanatory - you have a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) constraint on one of the columns you are updating and the update is trying to set two (or more) rows to have the same value and this is violating the constraint. This is not something StackOverflow can help with (especially since you have not shared any examples of your data or the DDL for the tables to be able to replicate this) - you will need to investigate your data and see where the duplication is occurring and whether it is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 0):

The code would be:

```
update table1  
   set column1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, 'OPRS', 'V'), 'ABV', 'T')  ;
```

I think you are just missing the `=`.

I would recommend adding:

```
where column1 like '%OPRS%' or column1 like '%ABV%'
```

This limits the update logic only to the rows that match.

Comment: Please don't answer typo question.  Thanks.

Comment: typo: *questions

Answer (score 0):

From your cursor query we can see that `table1.column1` and `table2.column3` are identifiers. These are also the columns you are manipulating in the UPDATE statements. So there is a gap in the procedural logic which means the SET clause is generating duplicate values in a unique column. It seems your data has a different state from what you think it has.

To fix this you need to do some investigation of the data.

1. Is `DB_KSS_ONLINE` the real name of `table1` or `table2` in your redacted code? This tells you which data you need to investigate.
2. Run a SELECT statement which reproduces the updated values. This tells you what additional rule (filter) you need to put in place.

Something like this:

```
SELECT e.column1
       , case when e.column1 like '2027044%' then
              REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, 'OPRS', 'V'), 'ABV', 'T')   
              else null 
         end as updated_col1
       , d.column3
       , REPLACE(REPLACE(column3, 'OPRS', 'V'), 'ABV', 'T') as updated_col3
       , e.column2
       , d.column4
  FROM table1 e, table2 d
  WHERE  e.column1 = d.column3
  order by 4 nulls last, 2 nulls last ;
```